# cant find the error on save record in Cakephp4

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-4.x

I am trying to save a new record from form data in cakephp4. This code worked in cakephp3.2 and has been updated but doesnt work. My issue is that I just get returned false? I cant do much with a 'false' when i try to save . I tried getErrors on $tutor which wasnt recognized either. How do I  find out where the error is?

```
    $tutor = $this->Tutors->newEmptyEntity();
            $tutor = $this->Tutors->patchEntity($tutor,$saveData,
                [
                    'associated' => [
                            'AvailabilityForTutors'=>["validate"=>false],
                            'AvailabilityForAssessments'=>["validate"=>false],
                            'Subjects'=>["validate"=>false]
                    ],
                    "validate"=>false
                ]);
            
            // debug($tutor);
              
            $tutor = $this->Tutors->save($tutor,[
                'validate' => false,
                'associated' => [
                    'AvailabilityForTutors',
                     'AvailabilityForAssessments',
                    'Subjects'
                ]
            ]);
        
             debug($tutor);//returns false? this doesnt tell me anything

 https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/orm/saving-data.html
```

Comment: Have you tried to write unit test for your code?

Comment: Please try again after bake model, `./cake bake model Tutors -f `

Answer (score 0):

I would at least move the saving to the table and wrap it in if/else to check if saving did happen and if not log correctly and return an error. To get the error change the save to the following code:

```
if ($this->Tutors->save($tutor,[
    'validate' => false,
        'associated' => [
            'AvailabilityForTutors',
            'AvailabilityForAssessments',
            'Subjects'
         ]
])){
    return $tutor;
} else {
Log::write(
    'emergency',
        'Unable to store tutor'
    );
    foreach ($tutor->getErrors() as $errorKey => $errorValue){
        Log::write(
            'emergency',
            'Error with field '.$errorKey
        );
    }
}
```

Do not forget to include: use Cake\Log\Log;

Run the code and check the logs in your logs folder

Answer (score -1):

I changed the return value on save and can test for errors

$result = $this->Tutors->save($NewTutor,[

I can get erros in NewTutor

Comment: Is this your answer?

Comment: just add an answer yourself if you dont like this answer.